# RegEx to match numbers with letters

Tags: regex

I want to match letters with numbers using regular expression  for example: I would like to match just (a15)or(A15)letter WITH a number. Not match if is just (a)the letter or (15) the number... but together. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just use `[a-zA-Z]\d+`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Id try this one [a-zA-z]+[0-9]+ and works pretty well but a Im gonna use [a-zA-z]+[0-9]+ to cover more than just one letter followed by a number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to express this as "any letter, followed by any number of digits": `[a-zA-z][0-9]+`.

Comment: Awesome Thanks A LOT!

Comment: I suggest modification to your regex, `[a-zA-z]+[0-9]+`, to cover this scenario of multiple prefixed letters (ej: "asdf15").

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[a-zA-Z][0-9]+` ?

Comment: @bkupfer OP's examples all have a single letter at the beginning. If the requirement is really to allow multiple letters at the beginning, you're right.